# What do we know about Hennig Brand's family?

Tags: germany, 17th-century

What do we know about [Hennig Brand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hennig_Brand)'s family? He is credited with the discovery of Phosphorus of course, but it appears he was married twice during his life. Did he have any children, and if so do we know their names?

Comment: Hi user2458076 and welcome to HistorySE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help](https://history.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 2):

Hennig Brand married twice and had at least two children with his first wife and also a stepson from his second marriage.

His first wife was a rich widow and this meant he could spend all his time on research. At least one of the children was a girl.

When his first wife died, he married Margaretha, also a rich widow. She had a son from her previous marriage and he worked for Brand as his assistant.

There is no mention of any other children or their names but it's quite likely that one or two died young as infant mortality was high in those days. One of the sources mentions he had a large family to support but says no more on this.

Sources

[How One Man’s Love of Urine Led to the Discovery of Phosphorus](https://gizmodo.com/how-one-man-s-love-of-urine-led-to-the-discovery-of-pho-1582537526)

[Hennig Brand 1630 - c. 1710](http://www.saburchill.com/HOS/chemistry/011.html)

[Hennig Brand](https://www.famousscientists.org/hennig-brand/)